# SQL base data type

Tags: sql-server

I need to get the list of all stored procedure and functions wherein instead of user defined data type SQL Server base data type is used. Is there any way to extract these details from SQL Server?

Comment: For parameters, you could execute `SELECT DISTINCT QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(object_id)) AS ObjectName
FROM sys.parameters
WHERE system_type_id = user_type_id;`. Data type details for variables are not persisted in the catalog views so you will need to parse the code to identify use of system types.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Is there a way to identify the same within the stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Parameter declarations with system data type specifications can be identified with this catalog view query:

```
SELECT
      QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(o.object_id)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(o.name) AS object_name
    , o.type_desc
    , p.name
FROM sys.objects AS o
JOIN sys.parameters AS p ON o.object_id = p.object_id
WHERE system_type_id = user_type_id;
```

Identifying variable declarations with system types will require parsing the underlying T-SQL code. One way to do this is with the T-SQL Script DOM library (Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll), which is part of the Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework (DacFx). The library is available as part of [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64/).

Below are example PowerShell scripts you can customize as needed. The main script (Find-SystemDataTypeDeclarations.ps1) downloads the NuGet package, parses code for existing objects using a [TSqlParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser), and then identifies [`SqlDataTypeReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.sqldatatypereference) fragments using a [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) with a custom visitor class (defined in the separate SqlDataTypeReference.ps1 script file).

The PowerShell visitor class script is in a separate script file because it is necessary to load the assembly before it can be compiled (it derives from the [`TSqlConcreteFragmentVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlconcretefragmentvisitor) defined in the DLL). Save both PowerShell scripts to the same folder with the file names indicated and execute with the command below after your customizations.

```
powershell -File "Find-SystemDataTypeDeclarations.ps1"
```

SqlDataTypeReference.ps1 script:

```
# visitor for SqlDataTypeReference fragments
class SqlDataTypeReferenceVisitor: Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.TSqlConcreteFragmentVisitor {

    [void]Visit ([Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.SqlDataTypeReference] $fragment) {
        Write-Host "`tSystem type $($fragment.SqlDataTypeOption) variable declaration found at line $($fragment.StartLine), column $($fragment.StartColumn)"
    }

}
```

Find-SystemDataTypeDeclarations.ps1 script:

```
# Add type from Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll assembly
Function Add-TSqlScriptDomType() {

    $dacFxNuGetUrl = "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64"
    $scriptDomAssemblyPath = "$PSScriptRoot\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll"

    if(![System.IO.File]::Exists($scriptDomAssemblyPath)) {
        # assembly doesn't exist in this script folder; download latest DacFx package from NuGet and extract the T-SQL Script DOM assembly here

        $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $dacFxNuGetUrl
        if ($response.StatusCode -ne 200) {
            throw "Unable to download Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom NuGet package: $($response.StatusCode) : $($response.StatusDescription)"
        }

        # decompress NuGet package to temp folder
        $tempZipFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath(), [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName() + ".zip")
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($tempZipFilePath, $response.Content)
        $response.BaseResponse.Dispose()
        $tempUnzipFolderPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath(), [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName())
        Expand-Archive -Path $tempZipFilePath -DestinationPath $tempUnzipFolderPath
        $tempZipFilePath | Remove-Item

        # copy Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll assembly and remove temp files
        Copy-Item "$tempUnzipFolderPath\lib\net*\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll" $scriptDomAssemblyPath
        $tempUnzipFolderPath | Remove-Item -Recurse

    }

    # load assembly for use in this PowerShell session
    Add-Type -Path $scriptDomAssemblyPath

}

# find system type declarations in specified script
Function Find-SystemDataTypeDeclarations($script) {

    $parser = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.TSql150Parser($true)
    $parseErrors = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.ParseError]
    $stringReader = New-Object System.IO.StringReader($script)
    $fragment = $parser.Parse($stringReader, [ref]$parseErrors)
    if($parseErrors.Count -gt 0) {
        throw "$($parseErrors.Count) parsing errors: $(($parseErrors | ConvertTo-Json))"
    }
    $visitor = [SqlDataTypeReferenceVisitor]::new()
    $fragment.Accept($visitor)

}

# ############
# ### MAIN ###
# ############
$connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2014;Integrated Security=SSPI"

try {

    # load T-SQL script DOM assembly
    Add-TSqlScriptDomType

    # dot source visitor class definition
. ".\SqlDataTypeReferenceVisitor.ps1"

    $query = @"
SELECT 
      QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(sm.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(sm.object_id)) AS object_name
    , o.type_desc
    , sm.definition
FROM sys.sql_modules AS sm
JOIN sys.objects AS o ON o.object_id = sm.object_id
WHERE o.type <> 'V';
"@

    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
    $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $connection)
    $connection.Open()
    $reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
    while($reader.Read()) {

        Write-Host "Processing $($reader["type_desc"]) $($reader["object_name"])"
        Find-SystemDataTypeDeclarations -script $reader["definition"]

    }

    $connection.Close()

}
catch {
    throw
}
```

Here's a sample snippet of the output from the AdventureWorks sample database:

```
Processing SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnGetAccountingStartDate]
    System type DateTime variable declaration found at line 3, column 9
    System type DateTime variable declaration found at line 6, column 20
Processing SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnGetAccountingEndDate]
    System type DateTime variable declaration found at line 3, column 9
    System type DateTime variable declaration found at line 6, column 45
Processing SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnGetContactInformation]
    System type Int variable declaration found at line 2, column 60
    System type Int variable declaration found at line 6, column 16
    System type NVarChar variable declaration found at line 7, column 17
    System type NVarChar variable declaration found at line 8, column 16
    System type NVarChar variable declaration found at line 9, column 13
    System type NVarChar variable declaration found at line 10, column 26
Processing SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnGetProductDealerPrice]
    System type Int variable declaration found at line 4, column 61
    System type DateTime variable declaration found at line 4, column 79
    System type Money variable declaration found at line 5, column 9
    System type Money variable declaration found at line 9, column 26
    System type Money variable declaration found at line 10, column 29
    System type DateTime variable declaration found at line 19, column 90
```